# what is にゃん meaning

Tags: meaning

Character1:「でもワタシ……ゾウさんが好き……」

Character2:「にゃんじゃそらー！？」

what is にゃん meaning in this sentence ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「にゃんじゃそらー！？」＝「何じゃそれは？！」

The な of 何 has been pronounced にゃ to give a quirky, catlike impression. じゃ is a version of だ.